# Custom column design

Tags: r, dataframe, import, read.table, customcolumn

I have a raw dataset and the columns are not clearly defined at all. When I go to import the data using "Read.Table" in R, it automatically tries to approximate where the columns begin and end. But it is not correct. I know the number of characters per variable, but I am not sure how to customize them as one would in Excel(=Left(x,3) OR  =MID(X,4,1)... etc.). Some variables are separated by spaces, some aren't. It is not consistent.

FYI: The document was originally ".dat", then I saved the file as a ".R" file.

[Here is an example of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFYa.png)

Any help is much appreciated! Let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`read_fwf`](http://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_fwf.html) from the great `readr` package, to specify the fix widths per variable.